# .Net MAUI view can not find observble collection properties

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, .net-maui, maui-community-toolkit

I have a xaml view with a CollectionView. The ItemSource is set to a list initiated in the xaml.cs class. The xaml view can not find the binding property "Id". If I remove id from the model I get the same error with "ListName".

> Binding: Property "Id" not found on
> "TestApp.Shared.Items.ViewModels.MainViewModel".

I have searched around and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72623945/net-maui-cannot-get-updated-fields-in-an-observable-collection-to-update-in-bou). But the fix does not solve my problem. Does anybody have an idea what the problem might be?
I am using:

> ```
> <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.0.0"/>
> ```

The code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestApp.Shared.Items.MainPage"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:TestApp.Shared.Items.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:MainViewModel">


     <CollectionView
        x:Name="CollectionOfListNames"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ListNames}">

        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>

                <Grid
                    x:DataType="viewmodel:MainViewModel"
                    Padding="0,5">

                    <Grid x:DataType="viewmodel:ListModel" ColumnDefinitions="2" Padding="0,5">

                        <Label Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Id}" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding ListName}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>

        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

    </CollectionView>

</ContentPage>
```

```
    namespace TestApp.Shared.Items.ViewModels
    {
        public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
        {
    
            [ObservableProperty]
            ObservableCollection<ListModel> listNames;
    
            public MainViewModel()
            {
                ListNames = new ObservableCollection<ListModel>()
                {
                    new ListModel(){ Id = 0, ListName = "Matlista"},
                    new ListModel(){ Id = 1, ListName = "Räkningar"},
                    new ListModel(){ Id = 2, ListName = "Att köpa idag"}
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

```
namespace TestApp.Shared.Items.Models
{
    public partial class ListModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private int id;

        public int Id
        {
            get => id;
            set => SetProperty(ref id, value);
        }

        private string listName;

        public string ListName
        {
            get => listName;
            set => SetProperty(ref listName, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to set the `x:DataType="viewmodel:MainViewModel"` also on the `Grid` inside of the `DataTemplate` but now for the `ListModel` object.

So:

```xml
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid x:DataType="model:ListModel" ColumnDefinitions="2" Padding="0,5">
            <Label Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Id}" />
            <Label Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding ListName}" />
         </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Note that the `ListModel` is in a different namespace, so add the right `xmlns` accordingly.

Right now XAML Compilation will think that all the children are using the `MainViewModel` and thus it (rightfully) can't find those properties.

Inside of a `DataTemplate` the scope changes, in your case to `ListModel`, we need to let XAML compilation know.

Comment: Something like this? Updated the code. Getting the same error.

Comment: No that doesn't seem right. You don't need the outer Grid, or maybe you do need the Grid, but you don't need the data type there. Let me update my answer

Comment: It works! Thank you for your help. I only got the choice "viewmodel:ListModel" instead of "model:ListModel". Btw your YT videos are great! Loving the MAUI framewwork.