# Databinding doesn't work for list in xamarin

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm currently working on building views with data binding in my Xamarin app. However, I've encountered an issue where the list, specifically the "ChecklistSections," doesn't get updated when I modify its values. Strangely, when I attempt to update the text for buttons, the data binding works perfectly fine. But for some reason, it's not working as expected for the list.

I'm looking for a solution to ensure that the "ChecklistSections" list gets updated properly through data binding, just like the buttons' text. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this data binding issue for the list would be greatly appreciated!

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:xxx.xxx.ExternalDisplay.App.ViewModels"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:xxx.xxx.ExternalDisplay.App.Converters"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:xxx.xxx.ExternalDisplay.Core.Models;assembly=xxx.xxx.ExternalDisplay.Core"
             x:Class="xxx.xxx.ExternalDisplay.App.Views.Checklist"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             x:DataType="viewModels:ChecklistViewModel"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
             BackgroundColor="Black">

<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <xct:InvertedBoolConverter x:Key="InvertedBoolConverter" />
        <converters:CheckedColorConverter x:Key="CheckedColorConverter" />
        <converters:InverseBooleanConverter x:Key="InverseBooleanConverter" />
        
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<StackLayout Padding="10">
    <Label Text="Checklist Items" FontSize="Large" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="0,20,0,0" />
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ChecklistSections}" HasUnevenRows="True"
                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ChecklistSection">
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="10">
                            <!-- Add padding to the StackLayout to create free space on all sides -->
                            <Label Text="{Binding ChecklistCategory.Name}" FontAttributes="Bold" Padding="5,0,0,0" FontSize="Header" TextColor="White" />

                            <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ChecklistItems}">
                                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ChecklistItem">
                                        <StackLayout Padding="15" Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="Purple">
                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <Label Text="{Binding ItemText}" FontSize="Large" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="End" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="End" >
                                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value}" Color="Green" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40"
                                                              CheckedChanged="GreenCheckBox_CheckedChanged"   />
                                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}" Color="Red" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="80" MinimumHeightRequest="50"
                                                              CheckedChanged="RedCheckBox_CheckedChanged" />
                                                    <BoxView Color="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource CheckedColorConverter}}" 
                                                             HeightRequest="20" 
                                                             WidthRequest="20" 
                                                             VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                             HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                                             Margin="5,0,0,0">

                                                        <BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="BoxView_Tapped" />
                                                        </BoxView.GestureRecognizers>

                                                    </BoxView>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                            <Editor  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="White"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
    <Button Text="{Binding ButtonText}" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryAccentColor}" BorderRadius="10" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="0,20" />
</StackLayout>
```

This is how I update the Checklist sections:

var a = ChecklistSections;

```
        foreach (var section in a)
        {
            var itemToUpdate = section.ChecklistItems.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == checklistItem.Id);
            if (itemToUpdate != null)
            {
                itemToUpdate.Value = value;

                // next two lines just for testing databinding
                ButtonText = itemToUpdate.ItemText;
                a[0].ChecklistCategory.Name = "hi hi hi";
                break; // Exit the loop after updating the item
            }
        }

        ChecklistSections = a;
```

checklistsections:

```
   private ObservableCollection<ChecklistSection> _checklistSections;
        public ObservableCollection<ChecklistSection> ChecklistSections
        {
            get => _checklistSections;
            set
            {
                {
                    _checklistSections = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ChecklistSections));
                }
            }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UI is not updating, when content of ObservableCollection is being updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75765267/ui-is-not-updating-when-content-of-observablecollection-is-being-updated). Many similar questions can be seen with this search: `site:stackoverflow.com xamarin observablecollection binding not updated when value changes`.

Comment: Are you expecting `ChecklistSections = a;` to cause the update? It won't, because `a` and `ChecklistSections` point to the same object. (If you look at an implementation of `OnPropertyChanged`, it usually does nothing when the incoming value is same as the property's current value. There are good reasons for this.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve then how can I update the checklistsections?  I need to update the value of boolean after user clicks on the checkbox on the screen and update the screen

Comment: Somewhere you are missing `INotifyPropertyChanged` or `SetProperty` or `OnPropertyChanged`. 1) Add to question the code for `class ChecklistSections`, and its properties. Start with the class definition line. It should look like `public class ChecklistSections : INotifyPropertyChanged` or `public class ChecklistSections : ObservableObject` or it inherits from a base class that has one of those. 2) ALSO, show the class definition line for whatever class (viewmodel?) includes `public ObservableCollection<ChecklistSection> ChecklistSections`. That class must have a similar inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the UI refresh automatically once changing the value of the bind property (e.g. `ItemText`), please recheck if you have implemented interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your model.

For example:

```
public class YourItemModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {            

        private string _itemText ;
        public string ItemText 
        {
            get => _itemText;
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _itemText, value);
            }
        }


        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    }
```

**Note:**

1. From document [ObservableCollection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-7.0),we could find that:

> `ObservableCollection<T>` represents a dynamic data collection that
> provides notifications when items get added or removed, or when the
> whole list is refreshed.

So, if you want to the UI refresh automatically once changing the value of the item model, it is useless to use code `ObservableCollection<ChecklistSection> ChecklistSections`.

2.It is recommended that you modify the value of the child element attribute directly on variable `ChecklistSections` instead of using intermediate variable `a`.

```
   //var a = ChecklistSections;

    foreach (var section in ChecklistSections)
    {
        //....
    }

    //ChecklistSections = a;
```

3.From you code, I find that you want to change the value of `ButtonText`  and the value of property `Name` of `ChecklistCategory`, then you also need to implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your corresponding model.

> ```
>       if (itemToUpdate != null)
>         {
>             itemToUpdate.Value = value;
>
>             // next two lines just for testing databinding
>             ButtonText = itemToUpdate.ItemText;
>             a[0].ChecklistCategory.Name = "hi hi hi";
>             break; // Exit the loop after updating the item
>         }
> ```

Comment: *"it is recommended that you modify the value of the child element attribute directly" - why? I don't see how that makes any difference. [Though it is a bit less confusing.]

Comment: I want to update an item inside the checklistscetions and the update UI. I've already defined INotifyPropertyChanged for all the fields. Any solution for that?

Comment: Could you please post more code snippets (e.g. the Item code of  `ChecklistSections` and the ViewModel of this page) so that we can help you better?